# groupメソッドが使えない理由がわかりません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

## 概要

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
`Connection.group(:user_id)`を実行すると、
`Object doesn't support #inspect`になってしまいます。

## 環境

Ruby 3.1.0
Ruby on Rails 6.1.4

## 該当のコード

model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :connections
end

class Connection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

上記の関係性で以下のような状況になります。

```rb
irb(main):038:0> Connection.group(:user_id)
  Connection Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `connections`.* FROM `connections` GROUP BY `connections`.`user_id`
(Object doesn't support #inspect)                                                                     
=>
```

```rb
irb(main):039:0> User.joins(:connections).group(:user_id)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `connections` ON `connections`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` GROUP BY `user_id`                                                                                                                  
=>                                                                                                                 
[#<User:0x0000000116f47d58                                                                                         
  id: 1,                                                                                                                                                                                    
  email: "demo-1@example.jp",
  created_at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 15:26:53.000000000 JST +09:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 17 May 2022 08:49:46.000000000 JST +09:00>,
 #<User:0x0000000116f47c90
  id: 2,
  email: "demo-2@example.jp",
  created_at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 15:28:27.000000000 JST +09:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 17 May 2022 08:51:19.000000000 JST +09:00>]
```

このように、`Connection`自体を`user_id`でGROUP BYしようとすると
`Object doesn't support #inspect`になってしまいますが、
これを`User`に内部結合として使うときちんと動作します。
今回はUserが重複しないConnectionを取得したいのですが、
前者はなぜ動かないのでしょうか？
また、「Userが重複しないConnection」を取得するにはどのような方法がありますでしょうか？
よろしくご教授ください。

## 補足

ちなみに`group`の使い方で調べた時に出てくるコードで、

```rb
User.group(:sex)
```

というのがあり、これに似たものとして

```rb
UserProfile.group(:sex) #User has_many :user_profilesです
User.group(:email)
```

なども試してみましたが、
いずれも`Object doesn't support inspect`でした。

Answer (score 1):

こちら解決しました。
本当に初歩的なことで、`group`はそもそも単体では使用できないそうです。
集計系のメソッドと併用すると機能します。

```rb
Connection.group(:user_id).minimum(:id).values
```

とすることでひとまず`user_id`でまとめた中で最小の`connection.id`を取得することが可能です。
（`maximum(:id)`にすれば最大のidが取得できます）
ActiveRecord_Relationで返す方法についても調べたのですが、
ちょっと上手くいかなかったのでまた研究してみます。
ありがとうございました。